# Transition left (on menu) not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

The transition left is not working on my menu. 
You can see it here 
[www.glennvanroggen.nl](http://www.glennvanroggen.nl)

In jQuery when you click the #show, it will toggle the class .menu_out on .menu.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#show').click(function(){
            $('.content').toggleClass("content_out");
        });
        $('#show').click(function(){
            $('.menu').toggleClass("menu_out");
        });
    });
```

But the thing is. the transition is not working. So the menu moves to the left but without a transition. I added a opacity transition just to check if it would work. And that one did. So I have no clue anymore.

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: -200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #F0D4B0;
    background-color: #002129;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: left 0.3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 5s ease-out;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.menu_out {
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #F0D4B0;
    background-color: #002129;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <div id="show">
        <p>Menu</p>
    </div>
    <div id="profile">
            <img src="images/glenn.jpg" alt="my face"/>
            <p>where dreams come true.</p>
        </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="love.html">Love</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I hope someone can help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Transition works on the same class or ID, you are using two different ones. Use jQuery's `animate()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified 2 transitions, the second (opacity) is overruling the first. Use this syntax to have more than one transition.

```
transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in, left  1s ease-in;
```

Or you could use 'all' when transition is identical on all changed properties:

```
transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
```

(Of course, all with vendor prefixes)

Also your JS should look like:

```
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $('.content').toggleClass("content_out");
        $('.menu').toggleClass("menu_out");
    });
```

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OviJUwac/1/edit)***

Comment: Wow! awesome I didn't know they could overrule each other. Thanks guys! It works now ;). http://www.glennvanroggen.nl

awesomeeee